# destroy watch in vnode context in vuejs2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-directives

In directive bind method, there is a `vnode.context.$watch`and every time that directive added to HTML, it is also adding another watcher with previous watcher. Because of that same watchers are calling more than once.

Is there any way to destroy the previous watcher when directive unbind method called.

```
Vue.directive("dynamic-lookup", {
    bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {        
        let dependency = setValue("dynamic-lookup-dependency");       
        if (dependency) {
            vnode.context.$watch(dependency, function (newVal, oldVal) { }); });
        }
    },
    unbind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
        console.log("unbind");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch), the `$watch` function it-self returns the unwatch function. You can save the returned function in `vnode.context` and call this function in directive unbind hook like this:

```
Vue.directive("dynamic-lookup", {
    bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
        let unwatch = vnode.context.$watch(vnode.context.property, function (newVal, oldVal) { 
                //Do something
            }); 
        });
        if(!vnode.context['unwatch'])
            vnode.context['unwatch'] = unwatch;
    },
    unbind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
        vnode.context.unwatch();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can unwatch your dependency when you want.

Documentation `vm.$watch` returns an unwatch `function` that stops firing the callback: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch

```
var unwatch = vnode.context.$watch(dependency, function (newVal, oldVal) {
});
// later, teardown the watcher
unwatch()
```

Comment: is there any way to call unwatch in unbind method ?

Comment: Maybe try this : this.unbind.unwatchDependency = ...; and in unbind : this.unwatchDependency ();